# Is drawRect "wasteful" when cropping? Is there an alternative?

Tags: ios, ios7, core-graphics, drawrect

Let's say you have an **original** image that is

```
200 high, 100 wide
```

Let's say you want to draw only a square of it.  Let's say, just the bottom square.

Let's say you want to draw it on to a new small image that is

```
20 high, 20 wide
```

Of course, you simply do this:

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake( -10,0, 20,20);
.. begin graphics context ..
[originalImage drawInRect:imageRect];
```

With drawRect, you supply a rectangle **the same full shape** (same proportions) of the **original image**, but expressed in the size of the **new canvas**. No problem.

BUT:

in the example, you are drawing **THE WHOLE ORIGINAL IMAGE -- THE WHOLE 200 HEIGHT** on to the new small square.

(Of course the "top half" misses the new canvas, and you only get the bottom half on the new canvas -- which is what you wanted.)

My impression is iOS **renders or calculates the "whole" original image**, and it only "puts on" the bottom half (in the example) on to the new canvas.

This seems very wasteful.

**IS THERE A FASTER WAY TO DO THIS?**

It seems like there should be a command, something like this:

```
drawThisPartOfTheOriginalImage: (0,100 to 100,200)
ontoThisPartOfTheNewCanvas: (0,20 to 20,20)
```

What's the situation?  Is there a more efficient command than drawRect when you are only **drawing a small part of the original image?**  Cheers

---

## CGContextClipToRect approach...(doesn't work!)

.

I experimented with CGContextClipToRect as Peter suggested below.

CGContextClipToRect indeed sets the area you will **draw to** on your "result" canvas.  I simply set it to the size of that result canvas (it would be 20.20 in the example above).  To repeat the aim here being to have iOS save time by avoiding pointlessly drawing the, err, not-drawn part of the original.

This example is for an original image 2000.2000 drawing on to a 500.500 (ie, only drawing the top left quarter of the original on to the result).

In fact notice it is slightly slower when you include the CGContextClipToRect, again suggesting iOS "knows when to stop" anyways.

```
// no need to "overdraw"... quickener turned OFF
//CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//CGContextClipToRect(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, resultSize.width,resultSize.height));
//Execution Time .................................. 0.443669

// no need to "overdraw"... quickener turned ON
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToRect(c, CGRectMake(0, 0, resultSize.width,resultSize.height));
//Execution Time .................................. 0.461845
```

As you can see it's a hair slower, actually, adding the CGContextClipToRect trick.

For the record, here is the exact routine used to crop an image:

```
-(UIImage *)simplishTopCrop:(UIImage *)fromImage
 {
 // check for zero fromImage.size.width etc etc
 
 CGSize resultSize = CGSizeMake(640,640);
 
 CGFloat scale = MAX(
  resultSize.width/fromImage.size.width,
  resultSize.height/fromImage.size.height);
 
 CGFloat width = fromImage.size.width * scale;
 CGFloat height = fromImage.size.height * scale;
 CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0,0, width,height);
 
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resultSize, NO, 0);
 
 // INSERT 'CGContextClipToRect' TRICK ABOVE, RIGHT HERE
 
 [fromImage drawInRect:imageRect];
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 return newImage;
 }
```

Comment: The difference is ~20 milliseconds? Did you run the tests multiple times? 20 milliseconds might be within the normal margin of error.

Comment: Hi Peter, sure, we experimented with it very, very, very extensively.  Annoyingly, there is no time saving.  As I say, on average, it's actually a hair slower (nothing you could notice) than simply omitting the two lines of CGContextClipToRect code. My guess is then, that, internally, iOS "knows" not to "overscan" anyway, so it is (apparently) very sadly completely pointless calling CGContextClipToRect.

Answer (score 4):

This is where clipping comes in. Clip to your dirty rect, then draw the whole image into your bounds. The clipping path will keep the rest of the image at least from appearing, and hopefully from being composited or sampled at all.

If your profiling in Instruments finds that that is not efficient enough, you might try cropping the image itself, using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`, and then drawing that image into your dirty rect. You may want to keep your cropped image around and only throw it away when the rect changes. One way or the other, cropping the image *may* be more efficient—but don't forget to profile both before and after to prove that.

Comment: @JoeBlow: [`CGContextClipToRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClipToRect).

Comment: Ah, regarding your first paragraph.  In fact CGContextClipToRect does not help.  Thus, I added code to use CGContextClipToRect to basically clip to the whole size of the new result image.  Thus, "avoiding" drawing to other than the target size (as asked in the question).  My results, unfortunately it takes the same time!  (Actually a hair longer, suggesting that in fact iOS anyway "knows" to do that.)  I will now investigate your second suggestion!

Comment: A CGContext has to clip to its bounds already. After all, the graphics buffer behind the context has a fixed size, so drawing at a negative coordinate (or one falling off the sides) would draw pixels outside the buffer and smash memory if there was no implicit clipping already. So all you're adding is overhead when it does both the implicit clipping and another run to clip to the rect you give it.

Comment: @uliwitness: So, you're saying that explicitly clipping to the dirty rect will cause the context to check coordinates against both rects, and not the intersection of them?

Comment: Hi @uliwitness: I'm not sure I agree with you, here.  We have utterly no clue how it is working internally.  For example: it might be that it is implemented like this:  (example implementation) *it does 'get ready to write' every pixel, at at the 'last moment' if that is off the target rectangle/memory - then (obviously) it doesn't write it*. That would be very sensible/reliable approach given the ridiculous variety of, um, topographies routines like drawToRect have to deal with. **IF** that was the case: recall that I am asking about the very specific situation of .. sorry, continued ...

Comment: (...continued due to the insane length limitation on comments here...) **IF** that was the case: recall that I am asking about the very specific situation of writing a simple bigger rect to the full target rect, then, indeed, I suppose, the CGContextClipToRect trick would be incredibly efficient, and we'd all be saying "my goodness, don't forget to use CGContextClipToRect, in that case, or you're ridiculously wasting writing". However (tragically) experimentation shows that Apple (apparently) already cover this simplification, you know? That seems to be the state of it...cheers

Comment: So just to be clear, this sentence: **"So all you're adding is overhead when it does both the implicit clipping and another run to clip to the rect you give it."** does, appear, to be absolutely correct based on our tests. (You guys can easily test it.)  My point in the previous two comment, UI, is that I don't see why that would "have to be" the case, would just depend how Apple did it.  (I think.)  Cheers !!

Comment: @Joe Blow, I have no clue how it works internally, beyond that it *must* clip to context edges because otherwise it would smash memory. But since your comment said it took "a hair longer", there is obviously some extra effort involved. This might just be Quartz looking at the clip rect and checking if it is the full context's rect and discarding it once before drawing starts. Or it may be that, to support transformations, it somehow needs to clip to this rect anyway. In any way, all I'm saying is the operation is unnecessary either way.

Comment: Hey @UI !  absolutely no problem, I understand. What I was saying in short: IMO the situation COULD BE that they implemented that in such a way that, in fact, it WOULD BE more efficient to "manually" check first.  However, in fact (our testing showed), the actual outcome is that you are 1000% correct, "the operation is unnecessary".